# JQuery submit runs multiple times after first submit

Tags: jquery

I have written a JQuery function to handle form submits that I use all over my site

My function is as follows:

```
$('.ajax_form').submit(function(e) {
    alert("submit");
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var frm = $(this);
    var modal = $(this).data("modal") || 'yes';
    
    if(!check_required( $(this) )) {
        alert("Some required fields are empty");
    } else {
        LoadModalBody('<h2 id="headingLoading" align="center">Loading...</h3><p align="center"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x"></i></p>');
        
        var i = 1;
        var sampleMessages = [
            "Still Loading...",
            "This is taking longer than normal, but we're working on it..."
        ];
        setInterval(function() {
          var newText = sampleMessages[i++ % sampleMessages.length];
          $("#headingLoading").fadeOut(500, function () {
            $(this).text(newText).fadeIn(500);
          });
        }, 10 * 1000);
        
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                CloseModal();
                
                if(modal === "no") {
                    $('.alert').remove();
                    /*var m = '<div class="alert alert-success">';
                    m += '<p><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> ' + data + '</p>';
                    m += '</div>';*/
                    $( data ).insertBefore( frm );
                    window.scrollTo(0,0);
                } else {
                    LoadModalBody(data);
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                //alert("There was an error");
                //console.log('An error occurred.');
                //console.log(data);
            },
        });
    }
});
```

I added the alert at the top of the submit for testing.

If the form is submitted once, you get the alert and then on the second submit the function is running 3 times and I cannot work out what is causing it.

I've tried adding `return false;` at the end of the `$('.ajax_form').submit(function(e) {` and also after the `$.ajax({` block.

`e.preventDefault();` is also in there at the top of the function which doesn't seem to stop it.

https://jsfiddle.net/pv0dbsLz/

Comment: You call   Initiate(); in LoadModalBody so each time you do that, you add the event handlers to existing event handlers

Comment: I see.. makes sense. But if I remote those calls it breaks other functions. I just added `$( ".ajax_form" ).unbind("submit");` above the .submit handler and it seems to be working - I'll keep testing

Comment: that would be .off instead o .unbind

Comment: Why do you call initiate in the function that is called in initiate?

Comment: @mplungjan `off` works as well - is that the best option?

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not sure what you mean by your last comment?

Comment: Don’t call initiate in the result. Add ONE event handler to a container (delegation) and cell the Ajax from a function you can call on load and on click